# What is the correct JSON to deserialize a map of sObjects?

Tags: json, generics

I'm trying to store a map of sObjects in a static resource. I want to be able to store default values for test setup methods. I was able to get it working with the following JSON in the static resource:

```
{ 
"Account" : "{\"attributes\":{\"type\":\"Account\"},\"BillingCity\" : \"testCity\"}",
"Opportunity" : "{\"attributes\":{\"type\":\"Opportunity\"},\"Name\" : \"testOpp\"}"
}
```

and here's the code:

```
String strJson = [SELECT body, name from StaticResource where Name =: myresource].body.toString();
mapJsonObjects = (Map<String, object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(strJson);
Account objAccount = (Account) JSON.deserialize((String) mapJsonObjects.get('Account'),Sobject.Class);
```

The JSON I would actually like to have in the static resource is:

```
{
   "Account":{
      "attributes":{
         "type":"Account"
      },
      "BillingCity":"testCity"
   }
   ...
}
```

but there is no way to deserialize this into an sObject as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to use the typed deserialize method as follows...

```
String jsondata = '{ "Account" : { "attributes":{"type":"Account"},"BillingCity" : "testCity"}, "Opportunity" : { "attributes":{"type":"Opportunity"},"Name" : "testOpp"}}';
Map<String, SObject> mapJsonObjects = (Map<String, SObject>)
    JSON.deserialize(jsondata, Map<String, SObject>.class);
Account objAccount = (Account) mapJsonObjects.get('Account');
System.debug('Account BillingCity is ' + objAccount.BillingCity);
Opportunity objOpportunity = (Opportunity) mapJsonObjects.get('Opportunity');
System.debug('Opportunity Name is ' + objOpportunity.Name);
```

The trick is using the [.class](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_type.htm) property to get the class type of the typed Map.

```
Map<String, SObject>.class
```

Results in

> DEBUG|Account BillingCity is testCity
>
> DEBUG|Opportunity Name is testOpp

Comment: Thanks so much! I was trying to deserialize into a map<string,sObject> for the longest time and eventually gave up after I kept getting weird errors.

Comment: Your very welcome! :)

Comment: As an addendum to this idea, I found it necessary to use sObject.clone() when creating multiple records based on the default values in the Objects generated by from one JSON record otherwise I got "Before Insert or Upsert list must not have two identically equal elements"